# How to write a query to group mongoDB documents and get total category details

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

```
[
  {
    "EmpId": "SV1011",
    "CheckInTime": "2019-11-01T06:43:40.551Z",
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "EmpId": "SV1011",
    "CheckInTime": "2019-11-01T06:43:41.305Z",
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "EmpId": "SV1011",
    "CheckOutTime": "2019-11-01T06:43:42.487Z",
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "EmpId": "SV1012",
    "CheckOutTime": "2019-11-01T06:43:48.915Z",
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "EmpId": "SV1012",
    "CheckInTime": "2019-11-01T06:43:49.704Z",
    "__v": 0
  }
]
```

How to use aggregate and group to get the output as below.

**Output**

```
[
  { "EmpId": "SV1011",
    "CheckInTime":{"2019-11-01T06:43:40.551Z",2019-11-01T06:43:41.305Z},
   "CheckOutTime":{"2019-11-01T06:43:40.551Z",2019-11-01T06:43:41.305Z}
  },
 { "EmpId": "SV1012",
    "CheckInTime":{"2019-11-01T06:43:40.551Z",2019-11-01T06:43:41.305Z},
    "CheckOutTime":{"2019-11-01T06:43:40.551Z",2019-11-01T06:43:41.305Z}
  },

]
```

Comment: ravi did my answer help? Please give some feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You can use addToSet operator to accomplish what you want.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$EmpId",
      "CheckInTime": {
        $addToSet: "$CheckInTime"
      },
      "CheckOutTime": {
        $addToSet: "$CheckOutTime"
      },

    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      "EmpId": "$_id",
      "CheckInTime": 1,
      "CheckOutTime": 1
    }
  }
])
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "CheckInTime": [
      "2019-11-01T06:43:41.305Z",
      "2019-11-01T06:43:40.551Z"
    ],
    "CheckOutTime": [
      "2019-11-01T06:43:42.487Z"
    ],
    "EmpId": "SV1011"
  },
  {
    "CheckInTime": [
      "2019-11-01T06:43:49.704Z"
    ],
    "CheckOutTime": [
      "2019-11-01T06:43:48.915Z"
    ],
    "EmpId": "SV1012"
  }
]
```

Playground:

https://mongoplayground.net/p/88W-GTtEHGI

Docs:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/